# Difference between complex.real and creal(complex) in Cython

Tags: python, cython, complex-numbers, complextype

To separate real part from complex parts in cython i have been generally using `complex.real` and `complex.imag` for the job. This does however generate code that is colored slight "python red" in the `html`-output, and i guess that I should be using `creal(complex)` and `cimag(complex)` instead.

Consider the example bellow:

```
cdef double complex myfun():
    cdef double complex c1,c2,c3
    c1=1.0 + 1.2j
    c2=2.2 + 13.4j
    c3=c2.real + c1*c2.imag
    c3=creal(c2) + c1*c2.imag
    c3=creal(c2) + c1*cimag(c2)
    return c2
```

The the assigments to `c3` give:

`__pyx_v_c3 = __Pyx_c_sum(__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(__Pyx_CREAL(__pyx_v_c2), 0), __Pyx_c_prod(__pyx_v_c1, __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(__Pyx_CIMAG(__pyx_v_c2), 0)));`

`__pyx_v_c3 = __Pyx_c_sum(__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(creal(__pyx_v_c2), 0), __Pyx_c_prod(__pyx_v_c1, __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(__Pyx_CIMAG(__pyx_v_c2), 0)));`

`__pyx_v_c3 = __Pyx_c_sum(__pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(creal(__pyx_v_c2), 0), __Pyx_c_prod(__pyx_v_c1, __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(cimag(__pyx_v_c2), 0)));`

where the first line to use the (python colored) construction `__Pyx_CREAL` and `__Pyx_CIMAG`.

Whys is this, and does it effect performance "significantly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the default C library
([complex.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/creal)) would work
for you.

However, it seems this library wouldn't give you any significant improvement
when compared to the `c.real` `c.imag` approach. By putting the code within a
`with nogil:` block, you can check that your code already makes no call to
Python APIs:

```
cdef double complex c1, c2, c3
with nogil:
    c1 = 1.0 + 1.2j
    c2 = 2.2 + 13.4j
    c3 = c2.real + c1*c2.imag
```

I use Windows 7 and Python 2.7, which doesn't have `complex.h` available in the
builtin C library for Visual Studio Compilers 9.0 (compatible with Python 2.7).
Because of that I created an equivalet pure C function to check any possible
gains compared to `c.real` and `c.imag`:

```
cdef double mycreal(double complex dc):
    cdef double complex* dcptr = &dc
    return (<double *>dcptr)[0]

cdef double mycimag(double complex dc):
    cdef double complex* dcptr = &dc
    return (<double *>dcptr)[1]
```

After running the following two testing functions:

```
def myfun1(double complex c1, double complex c2):
    return c2.real + c1*c2.imag

def myfun2(double complex c1, double complex c2):
    return mycreal(c2) + c1*mycimag(c2)
```

Got the timings:

```
In [3]: timeit myfun1(c1, c2)
The slowest run took 17.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
n intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 86.3 ns per loop

In [4]: timeit myfun2(c1, c2)
The slowest run took 17.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that a
n intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 87.6 ns per loop
```

Confirming that `c.real` and `c.imag` is already fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should not expect to see any difference: `__Pyx_CREAL(c)` and `__Pyx_CIMAG(c)` can be looked up [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/e6315294395ad44e667a804710938ee799575296/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L30), and there is no rocket science/black magic involved:

```
#if CYTHON_CCOMPLEX
  #ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __Pyx_CREAL(z) ((z).real())
    #define __Pyx_CIMAG(z) ((z).imag())
  #else
    #define __Pyx_CREAL(z) (__real__(z))
    #define __Pyx_CIMAG(z) (__imag__(z))
  #endif
#else
    #define __Pyx_CREAL(z) ((z).real)
    #define __Pyx_CIMAG(z) ((z).imag)
#endif
```

It basically says, these are defines and lead to a call without overhead of:

1. `std::complex<>.real()` and `std::complex<>.imag()`if it is c++.
2. [GNU extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#GNU-Extensions-for-Complex-Number-Types) `__real__` and `__imag__`, if it is gcc or intel compiler (intel added support some time ago).

You cannot beat it, e.g. in [glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/release/2.26/master/math/creal_template.c#L22), `creal` uses `__real__`. What is left, is Microsoft compiler (`CYTHON_CCOMPLEX` is not defined), for that [an own/special cython-class](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/e6315294395ad44e667a804710938ee799575296/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L81) is used:

```
#if CYTHON_CCOMPLEX
  ....
#else
    static CYTHON_INLINE {{type}} {{type_name}}_from_parts({{real_type}} x, {{real_type}} y) {
      {{type}} z;
      z.real = x;
      z.imag = y;
      return z;
    }
#endif
```

Normally, one should not write his/her own complex number implementation, but there is not so much you can do wrong, if only access to the real and imaginary parts is considered. I would not vouch for other functionality, but would not expect it to be very much slower than the usual windows implementation (but would like to see the results if you have some).

**As conclusion:** There is no difference for gcc/intel compiler and I would not fret too long about differences for others.